# Grid with RowSpacing(Xamarin Forms) and navigation

Tags: user-interface, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Now I'm working on updating the UI of my app(XF for Android). I found this UI solution for appbar(from source code [Evolve 2016](https://github.com/xamarinhq/app-evolve)):

[image]

It looks beautiful and is implemented simply:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
<Grid RowSpacing="0" >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackLayout BackgroundColor={StaticResource Primary}, Grid.Row=0/>
       <SearchBar/>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout Grid.Row=1>
       //other content
   </StackLayout>
 .....
```

For existing navigation(Master-Detail) it works fine. But I click by item (on this page) - than  open new page(no Master Detail). Work like this:

```
 await Navigation.PushAsync(new SessionDetailPage(), true);
```

I click back on toolbar - return to Session page than I get a **white line display for a short time**

[image]

it does not last long, a split second. then the white line disappears. But it's unpleasant to use.
Any ideas? How can I improve this?

Comment: Could you please share a basic demo that can reproduce the problem?

Comment: Hi, I use this source code -https://github.com/xamarinhq/app-evolve.
I added toolbaritem "Test" to session page. This is click handler
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new SponsorsPage(), true);
if you need I will create a simpler repository.

Answer (score 1):

Might be RowDefinition Height="Auto" calculating and resizing itself, try use absolute value to check if this is the cause.

Comment: I tried  absolute value, but I have "effect white line"

Comment: <Grid RowSpacing="0" > add VerticalOptions FillAndExpand to fill the page at start, might be it..

Comment: i don't understand, what do you have on row 0 and 1. Looking at pic, row0 is searchbar, row1 is rest of page, but you code shows different thing...

Comment: Try more: 1: ENTIRE GRID: VerticalOptions FillAndExpand + BackgroundColor - Primary. 2. STACKLAYOUT: BackgroundColor - White